# openstack - stack.sh fails on syntax errors

Tags: openstack

I am trying to install Devstack as non-root user, but getting errors.

The log directory contains only broken symbolic links stack.sh.log and stack.sh.log.summary (pointing to nonexistent files).

I've used the sample local.conf - the only change is that I defined the $DEST.

OS: RHEL 6.6

STDOUT/ERR:

```
/home/john/scripts/openstack/devstack/functions-common: line 68: conditional binary operator expected
/home/john/scripts/openstack/devstack/functions-common: line 68: syntax error near `"$1"'
/home/john/scripts/openstack/devstack/functions-common: line 68: `    [[ -v "$1" ]]'
./stack.sh: line 119: GetDistro: command not found
/home/john/scripts/openstack/devstack/functions-common: line 68: conditional binary operator expected
/home/john/scripts/openstack/devstack/functions-common: line 68: syntax error near `"$1"'
/home/john/scripts/openstack/devstack/functions-common: line 68: `    [[ -v "$1" ]]'
/home/john/scripts/openstack/devstack/stackrc: line 48: isset: command not found
/home/john/scripts/openstack/devstack/.localrc.auto: line 84: enable_service: command not found
/home/john/scripts/openstack/devstack/stackrc: line 498: is_package_installed: command not found
/home/john/scripts/openstack/devstack/stackrc: line 666: get_default_host_ip: command not found
/home/john/scripts/openstack/devstack/stackrc: line 668: die: command not found
WARNING: this script has not been tested on 
./stack.sh: line 179: die: command not found
./stack.sh: line 197: export_proxy_variables: command not found
./stack.sh: line 202: disable_negated_services: command not found
./stack.sh: line 209: is_package_installed: command not found
./stack.sh: line 209: install_package: command not found
[sudo] password for john: 
./stack.sh: line 231: is_ubuntu: command not found
./stack.sh: line 238: is_fedora: command not found
./stack.sh: line 301: safe_chown: command not found
./stack.sh: line 302: safe_chmod: command not found
./stack.sh: line 310: safe_chown: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/scripts/openstack/devstack/tools/outfilter.py", line 24, in <module>
    import argparse
ImportError: No module named argparse
```

Answer (score 0):

First, fix the missing module by using yum:
yum install python-argparse.noarch

Also you will need to run ./unstack.sh to clear the logs.

I had still faced this issue, so further debugging lead me to an issue when both python-zaqarclient and python-openstackclient were installed. As a quick solution I removed python-zaqarclient:

sudo pip uninstall python-zaqarclient

Then
- apt-get upgrade
- apt-get dist-upgrade
- ./stack.sh

Hope this helps!